# How to get currently selected value of a multiple select with Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a multiple select dropdown box.  I need to make an ajax call every time an item is selected, but am having a problem getting the specific value from the select menu.  Instead of retrieving the currently selected value, I get an array of all selected values.  How can I get the current selected value with JQuery?

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, just figured it out:

```
$(this).val();
```

Previously I was using `$('#id').val()` and that was returning the array.  `$(this).val()` will give you the current selected value.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the fiddle to get the currently selected value from multiselect dropdown

```js
var selectedOption;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#price-type').on('change', function(evt, params) {
    var currentSelection;
    if (selectedOption) {
      var currentValues = $(this).val();
      currentSelection = currentValues.filter(function(el) {
        return selectedOption.indexOf(el) < 0;
      });
    }
    selectedOption = $(this).val();
    $('#result').text(currentSelection);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="price-type" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="PRICE-1">PRICE-1</option>
  <option value="PRICE-2">PRICE-2</option>
  <option value="PRICE-3">PRICE-3</option>
  <option value="PRICE-4">PRICE-4</option>
  <option value="PRICE-5">PRICE-5</option>
</select>

<div id="result">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the click event, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8149592/171703) to capture it as each item is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can get selected value in alert:

```
$("#mydropdown").on('change', function(evt, params) {
alert(params.selected);
});
```

This will help you to get your exact value which you want.