# Get last selected value of multiple select element

Tags: jquery, select

I have a number of select boxes that have been set to accept multiple values.  Is there anyway that I can use jQuery to get the last selected value?  I've tried using the following:

```
var latest_value = $("option:selected",this).val();
```

and it returned nothing.  I only want the last selected value and not the array of values.

Thank you in advance

As requested here's the HTML I've cut the list down as it's too long:

```
<select id="style-list" name="style-list[]" class="attrs" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="7">2 Pack</option>
    <option value="10">3 Pack</option>
    <option value="12">4 Pack</option>
</select>
```

Then at the top of the page I have the following (I have 8 of these, but I've shown a few so that you can see that I'm using multiple instances of the multiselect widget:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#product-list").multiselect({
       selectedList: 4,
       noneSelectedText: "Product",
       minWidth: 190  
    }).multiselectfilter();

    $("#style-list").multiselect({
       selectedList: 4,
       noneSelectedText: "Style",
       minWidth: 190  
    }).multiselectfilter();


    $("#feature-list").multiselect({
       selectedList: 4,
       noneSelectedText: "Features",
       minWidth: 190  
    }).multiselectfilter();

});
```

and then I have this in a seperate js file:

```
$(function(){

    $(".attrs").on("multiselectclick", function(event, ui){

    var latest_value = $('option', this).filter(':selected:last').val(); 
    alert (latest_value);

    var view = $("#currentview").val();
    var page = 1;

    run_ajax(view,page);

    });

})
```

Thank you

Comment: If you're looking for the *most recently selected* option instead of the selected option that appears last in the list, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149532/how-to-get-the-last-selected-option-from-a-multiselect/.

Answer (score 16):

Use the [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector:

```
var latest_value = $("option:selected:last",this).val();
```

---

It *may* be that `this` in the context of the callback function doesn't refer to the `<select>` element itself, but instead to an element within it, so try the following:

```
var latest_value = 
$(this).closest('select').find('option').filter(':selected:last').val();
```

It may also be worth calling `console.log(this);` inside the callback function, just so you know what element you're actually working with.

Comment: +1, however, I'd suggest using `.filter()` with pseudo-classes for performance reasons. 
`var latest_value = $('option', this).filter(':selected:last').val();`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but neither suggestion worked.  I get the value undefined

Comment: @Amara In that case we'll need a little more information in the question - sounds like the original selector you had is also incorrect. Can you include the relevant HTML (actual HTML, not any server-side code that generates it) and the Javascript that calls that line of code?

Comment: Hi @AnthonyGrist I've added the information your requested.  Thank you for your help

Comment: @Amara I've edited my answer to include something else to try.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, but that didn't work either.  It's weird because if I use this code:                                                 var current_name = jQuery(this).attr('name');
alert (current_name);
var current_id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
alert (current_id);

Comment: Sorry hit the enter button twice so it wouldn't let me edit a second time.  When I enter the above code it displays the values as expected. Do you think it has anything to do with the fact that the values for the multiple select are stored in an array?

Comment: This not returning correct value when we select the option random from the multiselect, is there any other way to get the last selected value?

Comment: yes as @KannanK said, it's not giving correct value, because it's storing values based on drop down display order. please help with other solution

Comment: @Srikanth If you have a different problem - and it sounds like your requirements are different - you'll need to ask that as a new question.

Answer (score 5):

Use the last function:
like this

```
$("#style-list option:selected").last().val()
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code to get the latest selected option from multiple select list using Jquery :

```
var selected;
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#SELECT_ID').on('click', function() {
var latestSelected;
if (selected) {
    var currentOptionsValue = $(this).val();
    latestSelected = currentOptionsValue.filter(function(element) {
    return selected.indexOf(element) < 0;
  });
}
selected = $(this).val();
console.log( "latest selected option : " + latestSelected);
});
});
```

Comment: Hi Mahak your answer works good. I need to find latest  unselected value?

Comment: below i given one answer it will work for unselected also, try once @KannanK

Answer (score 2):

yes as @KannanK said, above answers not giving correct value, because it's storing values based on drop down display order, so if select from bottom to top, then will give wrong value.

I got one better logic to achieve this.
on every change of drop down will store into one global variable, so that we can get last selected value in **differOpt** variable.

```
var lastSelectedValues = [];
$('#yourID').change(function(e) {
    debugger;
    var currentSelVals = $('#yourID').val();
    var differOpt =arr_diff(currentSelVals,lastSelectedValues);
    lastSelectedValues = currentSelVals;
});
function arr_diff (a1, a2) {
    var a = [], diff = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        a[a1[i]] = true;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
        if (a[a2[i]]) {
            delete a[a2[i]];
        } else {
            a[a2[i]] = true;
        }
    }
    for (var k in a) {
        diff.push(k);
    }
    return diff;
}
```

**Updating one more better solution**
we can go with onChange option its giving correct value either select/unselect

```
$(function () { $('#datadownAutpState').multiselect(
    onChange: function(option, checked) {
        alert(option.val + ' option ' + (checked ? 'selected' : 'deselected'));
    }
});});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you just need to slightly update your JS file

```
$(function(){

    $(".attrs").on("multiselectclick", function(event, ui){

        var latest_value = ui.value; 
        alert (latest_value);

        var view = $("#currentview").val();
        var page = 1;

        run_ajax(view,page);

    });

})
```

The second parameter `ui` has the following value:

```
{
    value: 'some value',
    text: 'option label',
    checked: true //whether option is selected or deselected
}
```