# <select><option> (multiselect), get last $(this).val() checked ONLY

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

I have a select option, with `onclick`, I would like to give the argument of the last option checked (his class name) ONLY.... but `$(this).val()` return : `var1, var2, varN...`

```
<select id="hiddenColumns" onchange="alert($(this).last().val())" multiple="multiple">
    <option className="imgClass"  >Images</option>
    <option className="idClass">Identifiant</option>
</select>
```

I find the same question here but I don't find a working solution in.

[Get last selected value of multiple select element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456954/get-last-selected-value-of-multiple-select-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not set a listener to options instead of the select?

```js
$('#hiddenColumns option').click(function(event) {
    if ($(this).is(':selected'))
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="hiddenColumns" multiple="multiple">
    <option className="imgClass"  >Images</option>
    <option className="idClass">Identifiant</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Drosam, your solution works ! 
But I use https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect to create a checkbox list and it do not works with that, do you know why ?
I remember there is a lot of method implementation and I will check the doc maybe there is a specifical method to do it. :)

Comment: I took a look to the doc and I think you could use `onChange` event. Check this, I think it is what you want http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-onChange

Comment: Thank you Drosam, this is what I have do yes :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the last selected option you can either use the jQuery method

```
$(this).find(':selected').last();
```

or the selector

```
$(this).find(':selected:last');
```

To then get your attribute "className" use .attr('className')

In total it can look like this

```
$(this).find(':selected:last').attr('className')
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and your Answer PostCrafter.
But your solution only give me the last checked option physically in the list and not the last option i really checked.

Comment: Seems like I missunderstood your question, @drosam's answer looks pretty much exactly like how I would solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, then I found the solution :
I recommand to use bootstrap multiselect for multiselect select option.
Then you can use this when you create your list and then you have a method to get the last value checked :
http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example-onChange').multiselect({
            onChange: function(option, checked, select) {
                alert('Changed option ' + $(option).val() + '.');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```