# Get last changed option element from multiple select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, event-handling

I need the last(1) changed option element from a multiple select box with jQuery or crossbrowser native js code.

(1)last = time not order!

```
<form id="form-with-msb">
    <select multiple id="multiple-select-box">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="1">xxx</option>
        <option value="2">yyy</option>
        <option value="3">zzz</option>
    </select>
</form>

$( "#form-with-msb" ).on( "change", "#multiple-select-box", function() {
  // get last changed option element from multiple select box
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"time not order"_? The last option that was selected before the user selected another option?

Comment: @Patrick Evans: Yes, the last option that was selected (and not the last element in order of selected option elements).

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149532/how-to-get-the-last-selected-option-from-a-multiselect/

Comment: @npearson: Solution with click event for options don't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `data` attribute to store the previously selected options.

**i.e:**

```
<select data-last='' ...>...</select>
```

Every `onChange` call will store the selected options into the `data` attribute.

```js
$("#form-with-msb").on("change", "#multiple-select-box", function() {
  var last = $(this).data('last');
  console.log(last.split(','));

  var selected = [];
  $(this).children(':selected').each(function(idx, opt) {
    selected.push($(opt).text());
  });
  $(this).data('last', selected.join(','));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form-with-msb">
  <select data-last='' multiple id="multiple-select-box">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="1">xxx</option>
        <option value="2">yyy</option>
        <option value="3">zzz</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Was a good idea to save data in "data-last". I have changed "this" to "event.currentTarget" and added a function for data difference.

Answer (score -1):

You can define one array object to record all actions the user performs. Then fetch the last one of the array object as the last change. Even you can implement redo/undo function by this mechanism.

```js
var G_ACTION_CACHE = []
$( "#form-with-msb" ).on( "change", "#multiple-select-box", function() {
  // get last changed option element from multiple select box
  if(G_ACTION_CACHE.length===0){
    console.log("NO ACTION BEFORE");
  }
  else{
    console.log(G_ACTION_CACHE[G_ACTION_CACHE.length-1]);
  }
  var current_actions = [];
  $.each($( "#form-with-msb" ).find("option:selected"), function(index, item) {
    current_actions.push({'ID':index, 'VALUE':$(item).text()});
  });
  G_ACTION_CACHE.push(current_actions);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form-with-msb">
    <select multiple id="multiple-select-box">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="1">xxx</option>
        <option value="2">yyy</option>
        <option value="3">zzz</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: This doesn't really work. If you make multiple selections it logs out things like "xxxyyyzzz"

Comment: Not to mention you don't need to go to the trouble of finding all selected options when `$(this).val()` gives you an array of the selected values.

Comment: Is the storage and comparison of the selected values the only solution? Can not access the event?

Comment: Sorry, updated my codes to support multiple selection.